# How to get message name from field descriptor protobuf

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers

I would like to be able to access the message name given one of its variables. For example lets say in the .proto file I have.

```
syntax = "proto3";
package one;

message Foo{
 uint32 x = 1;
}
```

And then I use a field descriptor to iterate through the contents of the message which in this case is just one variable. I know I can use FieldDescriptor::full_name() but that returns "one.Foo.x" and if I use FieldDescriptor::name() that returns just "x". Is it possible to return "Foo" only?

Comment: You are probably looking for `FieldDescriptor::containing_type`. This gives you `Descriptor*` for the containing message, which you can then interrogate as necessary.

Comment: ah derp right, I was too focused on field descriptors that I forgot about the descriptor. What I was looking for was Descriptor::name() thanks.